# How can I loop through a DataGridView created on the main form in a BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I want to loop through a DataGridView that is created on the main form in a BackgroundWorker to export the data  to a CSV file.  The BackgroundWorker is created on a separate form where the progress of the export will be displayed via a progress bar.  Here is the code on the export form that calls the BackgroundWorker:

```
private DataGridView exportGrid;

public void ExportCSV(DataGridView mainGrid)
{
    this.exportGrid = mainGrid;

    //Set progress bar maximum
    progressBar1.Maximum = mainGrid.Rows.Count;

    if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
    {
        //Start the asynchronous operation
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    //Show the form
    this.ShowDialog();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    //Write data rows
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in exportGrid.Rows)
    {
        //Check if the background worker has been cancelled
        if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.Visible)
                {
                    //Do CSV writing here...
                }
            }

            //Report current progress to update UI
            worker.ReportProgress(row.Index + 1);
        }
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Update progress bar
    this.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //Close the form once the background worker is complete
    this.Close();
}
```

This code has been causing the following errors:

- BindingSource cannot be its own data source. Do not set the
  DataSource and DataMember properties to values that refer back to
  BindingSource.
- Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'mainGrid' accessed from a
  thread other than the thread it was created on.

I assume that these are because I am accessing the DataGridView in a thread that did not create it.  What is the best way to go about doing this?  Is it even possible?

**Update:**

The reason I am looping through the DataGridView instead of the datasource is that the users will be changing the column order, sort order and showing/hiding columns of the grid and they want these changes reflected in the exported data.  Is there a different way to handle this?

Comment: How big is this DataGridView in terms of rows?

Comment: Currently it has over 80,000 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff in my opinion you are doing at minimum two mistakes in here:

- Exporting data from a UI control instead of doing it from the data source;
- Trying to access a UI control from a background thread;

I just would not try to access a UI control (Grid in your case) in a form which is not even the form where the background thread is declared, code will be so unclear and unreadable...

then consider that UI controls are used to render data in the UI; whenever you need to access the data for anything else than rendering in the screen you'd better access directly the datasource used to populate the UI.

Comment: The reason I am trying to use the grid instead of the datasource is because the users want to be able to reorder, sort or hide the columns before they export it and the resulting data will look the same.

Comment: I see, how would you react and handle if while exporting from worker thread UI not blocked and user changes order and sort again?

Comment: Well technically, the second (export) form is called with `ShowDialog()` so the user would not be able to get back to the main form.  However, I do see how using a UI control like this is not the right way to do it.  Are there any alternatives?

Comment: if you use ShowDialog and not allow to do anything else in UI at that point I would export from the UI thread because UI is blocked anyway... if I can suggest real alternatives, get the DevXpress XtraGrid and just call the handy method: myGrid.ExportToExcel(...) ;-)

Comment: Well the UI of the main form is blocked, but the UI of the secondary (export form) is not blocked.  I update a progress bar on this form so the users know approximately how long the export process will take.

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into this before.  Here's how I did this.  This is taken straight out of the project I did this in.  You should be able to get the idea of how to set up the threading to make this work.  I didn't include the methods that actually write the CSV file, I'm assuming your main problem is with the threading.  And as Davide Piras said, it's probably not a good idea to write the data directly from a control.

The BackGroundWorker's EventHandlers:

```
    #region TableWorker Events
    void TableWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        bool done = false;
        GetSwitch();
        ProgressLabel.Visible = true;
        while (!done)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                TableWorker.ReportProgress(i);
            }
            done = Export.ExportDataTable(SaveFile, DataTable);
        }
    }

    void TableWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Progress.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
        Progress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        ProgressLabel.Text = "Writing File: " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "% Complete";
    }

    void TableWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Progress.Value = 100;
        ProgressLabel.Visible = false;
        Progress.Visible = false;
        //MessageBox.Show("Export Completed!");
        TableWorker.Dispose();
        ExportButton.Enabled = true;
        this.Close();
    }
    #endregion
```

Event that starts the BackgroundWorker.

```
    private void EntireTableButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dialogResult = Export.SetSaveDialog(SaveFile, ".csv", "csv file (*.csv)|*.csv");

        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            TableWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            this.Hide();
            ProgressLabel.Visible = true;
            ProgressLabel.Text = "Retrieving Data...";
            Progress.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
            Progress.Visible = true;
            ExportButton.Enabled = false;

            while (TableWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            Progress.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

The Background worker's ReportProgress method will allow you to pass the progress to the ProgressChanged event.  By doing this you can update the progress bar on another form.

Comment: I believe my problem is that I am looping through a UI control in the background worker.  If I replace this loop with a regular `for` loop everything with the thread works correctly.  So I guess I'm looking for an alternative to using the Grid even thought I need to keep the formatting (order, hide, sort) that the user set.

Comment: Is your datasource in a database?  When I make a call to the Export class, I am basically taking filters I had on the table and creating a SQL command, so the database will return a DataTable that is filtered exactly like a user filtered the DataGridView.